# What's the purpose of boost::detail::addr_impl_ref?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, casting

Inside boost there's [boost::detail::addr_impl_ref](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/utility/addressof.hpp#L24) struct that basically has a constructor accepting a `T&` reference and an overloaded `operator T&()` that returns that reference. It is used in the implementation of [boost::addressof()](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/utility/addressof.hpp#L59):

```
template<class T> T* addressof( T& v )
{
    return boost::detail::addressof_impl<T>::f( boost::detail::addr_impl_ref<T>( v ), 0 );
}
```

`boost::detail::addressof_impl<T>::f()` accepts `T&` as the first parameter. `boost::addressof<T>()` also has `T& v` as the parameter.

Why is `boost::detail::addr_impl_ref()` temporary object used here to store and return `T&` instead of just passing `T& v`?

Comment: Possibly a workaround to avoid invoking the `op&()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prevents other implicit conversion operators of `T` to be a part of the conversion.

EDIT: For instance:

```
struct foo
{
   operator foo*()
   {
      return 0;
   }
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what could go wrong without using that function?

Comment: Do you mean that with the example provided boost::detail::addressof_impl<T>::f( T*) could be called? Is that the only problem possible?

Comment: Yes, without it the two `addressof_impl<T>::f` overloads have similar conversion, resulting in a compile time error.